# How to change voice of sentence: Ram is fan of Sham

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I want to change voice of following sentence (where Ram is a person, and Sham may be an artist):

> Ram is fan of Sham

Is something like "Sham is fanned by Ram" correct? I am looking for a word that can be paired with "is". Following is an example:

> Ram follows Sham --> Sham is followed by Ram.

Here, in this sentence, "Is Followed" is what I need. So, when I say "Is Fanned", is it right?

Comment: Look at meanings of “fan” in a dictionary.

Comment: It should be "Ram is **a** fan of Sham" - _fan_ being a noun, nor a verb.

Answer (score 0):

> (**CoGEL § 2.21**) **Active and passive structures**
>
> Clauses containing a noun phrase as object are distinguished by the fact that
> they are usually matched by passive clauses, in which the object noun phrase
> now appears as subject (V<sub>pass</sub> = passive verb phrase), cf Table 2.21 on the
> next page. As type SVOO clauses have two objects, they can often have two
> passive forms - one in which the indirect object becomes the subject, and
> another in which the direct object becomes subject.

[image]

O<sub>d</sub>: direct object
O<sub>i</sub>: indirect object
C<sub>s</sub>: subject related complement
A: adverbial
A<sub>s</sub>: subject related adverbial

In sentences where the main verb is "to be" there cannot be an object, and so voice is not a concept relevant to this verb and sentences that contain it. In fact it is not relevant to sentences that contain a copular verb, such as "to seem" and to "become".

- The man on the bench seemed sick. (*no passive*)
- The country is becoming poorer and poorer. (*no passive*)

Answer (score 0):

"Sham is fanned by Ram" would be the passive version of "Ram fans Sham". Both suggest someone wafting air in the other's direction, so are not what you want here.

([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fanning) has a good list of meanings for "fan" when used as a [mainly transitive] verb.)

[Fans / is fanned] and [follows / is followed] are verb structures, while in the original sentence "is a fan" uses "fan" as a noun - (originally abbreviated from "fanatic"). The noun structure "Ram is a ... of" can be given a different subject by saying "has Ram as a ...". In this case, the verb we're trying to change is the verb "is" ("to be").

For the "follow" example, we could say "Ram is a follower of Sham" and "Sham has Ram as a follower"

So Sham has Ram as a fan. (Which is more fun to say than I thought it would be.)

Comment: *"Ram is fanned by Sham"* is wrong. "To fan" is not a transitive verb (it is not used as a verb at all in this sense) and, as such cannot be made passive. *Sham has Ram as a fan.* is not a passive.

Comment: @Greybeard - It's right if Ram is blowing air at Sham, but that's not what the OP is looking for. But it's true that I picked up on the word "passive" and overused it. Editing.

Comment: Other way round. Sham blows air at Ram.